# Which games on Xbox360 support 3D?

Tags: xbox-360, stereo-3d

I know there are 3D games for PC and for PS3, but are there any for Xbox 360? Is there a full list somewhere and what 3d technology do they use (what kind of TV do you need)?

Comment: I *want* to say none of them do, but am not confident enough in that to make it a real answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there are only a handful of games to the xbox360 that supports 3D, these games are:

- 3D Infinity
- Avatar: The Game
- Batman: Arkham Asylum (GOTY Edition)
- Call of Duty: Black Ops
- Enslaved: Odyssey to the West
- G-Force
- Invincible Tiger: The Legend of Han Tao
- Madden NFL 11
- Shaun White Skateboarding
- Skate 2

[Xbox 360 3D Games List](http://www.3dtested.com/3d-xbox-360-games-list/) - is a list that contains 3D supported games, as well as upcoming (confirmed and unconfirmed) 3D games. (This list is being updates)

You can also find a guide to [getting started with 3D](http://www.3dtested.com/getting-started-with-3d/) at the same site.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a full list but Call of Duty: Black Ops for the 360 does.